# Joining 2 Tables: CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is based on CodeIgniter 2.2.  I'm joining 2 tables which is *items* and *item_inventory_pharmacy* since I am getting data from the table *items*

Below are the columns of each table

**items**

- item_id
- item_name
- item_category
- item_price
- item_tax

**item_inventory_pharmacy**

- item_id
- item_name
- item_quantity
- sales_id

I tried doing a code but failed to do it correctly

```
<?php               
                    $this->db->where('sales_id', $data->sales_id); 
                    $this->db->join('items', 'item_id = item_id');


                    $logsStock = $this->db->get('item_inventory_inpharmacy');
                    $x=1;
                        foreach ($logsStock->result() as $stockRow)
                          {                                                                
                           echo '<tr>';
                           echo '<td>'.$x++.'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.$stockRow->item_id.'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.$stockRow->item_name.'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.$stockRow->item_retailprice.'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.$stockRow->item_quantity.'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.$stockRow->item_tax.'</td>';                           
                           echo '</tr>';                                                           
                          }
                  ?>
```

I hope anybody can help. :)

Comment: I don't see any `JOIN` commands being used, nor do i see `sales_id` in the tables you mentioned ? Can you explain more in details what the problem is?

Comment: thanks @CodeGodie. I missed those. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your join command needs to know which table belongs to what join. Also, try doing a LEFT join in order to get data that does not have a match.

Change this:

```
$this->db->join('items', 'item_id = item_id');
```

To this:

```
$this->db->join('items', 'items.item_id = item_inventory_inpharmacy.item_id' , 'left');
```